# Android Full Screen images Slider with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-fullscreen

I want to an images slider inside my app! 
after a long search I found that I have to use a `ViewPager` to get things done! 
 I need to make the `Viewpager` to be come full screen when I select image and slides left and right to show previous and next image in the slider..

here's my code :

FullScreenFragment.java

```
 package com.mustafataj.zoalvision.checkmyride.fragments;


 import android.annotation.TargetApi;
 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.net.Uri;
 import android.os.Build;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.os.Environment;
 import android.os.Handler;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
 import android.view.KeyEvent;
 import android.view.LayoutInflater;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.view.ViewGroup;
 import android.view.WindowManager;
 import android.widget.Button;
 import com.mustafataj.zoalvision.checkmyride.R;
 import com.mustafataj.zoalvision.checkmyride.adapter.SlidingImage_Adapter;
 import com.viewpagerindicator.CirclePageIndicator;
 import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
 import java.io.File;
 import java.io.FileOutputStream;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import butterknife.ButterKnife;
 public class FullScreenFragment extends Fragment implements Runnable {
 View v;
 ViewPager pager;
Button share;
private static final Integer[] IMAGES= {R.drawable.demo_car_thumb_4,R.drawable.demo_car_thumb_3,R.drawable.demo_car_thumb_2,R.drawable.demo_car_thumb_1};
private ArrayList<Integer> ImagesArray = new ArrayList<Integer>();

public FullScreenFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_full_screen, container, false);
//pager = v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
share = v.findViewById(R.id.share);
   // pager.setAdapter(new SlidingImage_Adapter(getActivity(),ImagesArray));
    init();
share.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
       share.setType("image/jpeg");
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        File f = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator +"thumb.jpg");

        try {
            f.createNewFile();
            FileOutputStream fo = new FileOutputStream(f);
            fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
 share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file://sdcard/temp/jpg"));
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share,"Share Image to ..."));

    }
});
    return v;
}

private void init() {
    for(int i=0;i<IMAGES.length;i++)
        ImagesArray.add(IMAGES[i]);

    pager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);


    pager.setAdapter(new SlidingImage_Adapter(getActivity(),ImagesArray));



}

@Override

    public void onDestroy () {

        super.onDestroy();

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 10) {

            unregisterSystemUiVisibility();

        }

        exitFullscreen(getActivity());

    }




public static boolean isImmersiveAvailable() {

    return android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19;

}



public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {

    if (hasFocus) {

        _handler.removeCallbacks(this);

        _handler.postDelayed(this, 300);

    } else {

        _handler.removeCallbacks(this);

    }

}



public void onKeyDown(int keyCode) {

    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP)) {

        _handler.removeCallbacks(this);

        _handler.postDelayed(this, 500);

    }

}



@Override

public void onStop() {

    _handler.removeCallbacks(this);

    super.onStop();

}



@Override

public void run() {

    setFullscreen();

}



public void setFullscreen() {

    setFullscreen(getActivity());

}



public void setFullscreen(Activity activity) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 10) {

        int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;



        if (isImmersiveAvailable()) {

            flags |= View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION |

                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;

        }



        activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flags);

    } else {

        activity.getWindow()

                .setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    }

}



public void exitFullscreen(Activity activity) {

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 10) {

        activity.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_VISIBLE);

    } else {

        activity.getWindow()

                .setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN,

                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

    }

}



private Handler _handler = new Handler();



@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)

private void registerSystemUiVisibility() {

    final View decorView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();

    decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {



        @Override

        public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {

            if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {

                setFullscreen();

            }

        }

    });

}



@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)

private void unregisterSystemUiVisibility() {

    final View decorView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();

    decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(null);

}}
```

and this my adapter class:

SlidingImage_Adapter.java:

```
     package com.mustafataj.zoalvision.checkmyride.adapter;

     import android.content.Context;
     import android.os.Parcelable;
     import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
     import android.view.LayoutInflater;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.view.ViewGroup;
     import android.widget.ImageView;
     import com.mustafataj.zoalvision.checkmyride.R;
     import java.util.ArrayList;

      /**
     * Created by Shashoug on 02/07/18.
       */

     public class SlidingImage_Adapter extends PagerAdapter {
     private ArrayList<Integer> IMAGES ;
     private LayoutInflater inflater;
     private Context context;
     public SlidingImage_Adapter(Context context,ArrayList<Integer> IMAGES) {
     this.context = context;
     this.IMAGES=IMAGES;
     inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
   @Override
   public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView((View) object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return IMAGES.size();
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup view, int position) {
    View imageLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.sliding_image_layout, view, false);

    assert imageLayout != null;
    final ImageView imageView = (ImageView) imageLayout
            .findViewById(R.id.image);


    imageView.setImageResource(IMAGES.get(position));

    view.addView(imageLayout, 0);

    return imageLayout;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view.equals(object);
}
@Override
public void restoreState(Parcelable state, ClassLoader loader) {
}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {
    return null;
}}
```

and this my fragment_full_screen.xml file:

```
     <RelativeLayout   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:background="@color/ms_black"                tools:context="com.mustafataj.zoalvision.checkmyride.fragments.FullScreenFragmen">
                    <Button
                      android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
               android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
               android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
               android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:backgroundTint="#ED6326"
         android:background="@drawable/ic_share"
         android:id="@+id/share"
         android:layout_width="30dp"
         android:layout_height="30dp" />
         <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
       android:id="@+id/pager"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent">
      </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
      </RelativeLayout>
```

Full_screen_viewer.xml :

```
               <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.mustafataj.zoalvision.checkmyride.fragments.FullScreenFragment">
<fragment
    class="com.mustafataj.zoalvision.checkmyride.fragments.FullScreenFragment"
    android:id="@+id/titles"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```

and when I click to show the full screen fragment nothing popups without any errors? 
how to fix that? 
and If there any way to implement my idea feel free to guide me.
thanks in advance :)

Comment: The size of an Activity's window can't be changed after an activity has been created. You need to start a new Activity.

Comment: yeah I have an activity to show the fragment

Comment: No, I mean you need to start a new Activity using the method `getActivity().startActivity(this, NewActivityName.class)`

Comment: I have an activity that contains an image that I can click to go the activity that show the fragment..

Comment: please review my code for any modifications or any logical issues ..

Comment: the point is .. I want to click on image at specific activity .. the image will take me to activity that contains fragment .. that fragment shows viewpager to show the slider ..